# Making sitemap for the search engine crawler for a website which requires login before viewing any content

Tags: php, seo, sitemap

I have a php mysql website which requires the users to signup at the first page(homepage) then only they can browse the contents of the website. Every page produces a login form if user is not logged in and content is shown only when logged in. The only IPs which could register are that of my college's wireless network.

So I need to have a sitemap or some kind of other way so that the crawlers( every search engine's) can view the content of the website which requires login.
**Please post the accepted or ethical way only.**

I currenlty do not have a search inside my website so users will not be able to find the content through it so I want them to easily come through the search engine using say "search text mydomain.com".

I read this 
[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125548/can-search-engines-bots-crawl-pages-requiring-login) but could not find the solution.

Comment: If your content should be accessible only by a specific set of users, then it should not be visible to search engines.

Comment: Okay but say if someone types "search text and mydomainname.com" specifically then the result should be from my website.
So does google provides any service for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Google Custom/Site/Enterprise Search is an option:

http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gss.html

It can access secured content:

http://support.google.com/gsa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15855

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to an intranet. Creating an XML site map, meta tags, or robots.txt file for a domain that is only viewable to certain users is completely superfluous. You simply don't need to. If they have a login account, they must know the site exists.

That would be like giving your imaginary friend a name. ;)

Comment: no I am not referring to the intranet.....And they know the site exists but I want them to be able to search for any content from google using "search text mydomainname.com" so it will be easily searchable using google...........but I think I will have to implement some search capabilities in my website only......

Comment: If you're only trying to parse the content found on your page then searching in a global engine like Google is a bit silly. I'd recommend you use some JavaScript if you want a quick client-side search.  [link](http://www.tipue.com/search/)

Answer (score 0):

Content visible only to authorized users, should not be visible to anyone else, including search engines.

If you want to let your users search your site, you should add search capability in your user area. This has nothing to do with Goodle or any oter search engine.